# Attribute Error: openai has no attribute Image

Tags: python, openai-api

So I was getting my hands-on on the new DALL.E api for Python which has been made public. I was getting the Attribution Error as it was not detecting the Image model in Open ai after running the following code:

```
response = openai.Image.create(
  prompt="a white siamese cat",
  n=1,
  size="1024x1024"
)
image_url = response['data'][0]['url']
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found the solution. You have to upgrade your openai library with code:

```
pip install --upgrade openai
```

Restart the kernel, and enjoy :)

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem. I noticed my python is 3.7.0, which only supports up to openai=0.8... for openai 0.25.0, will need at least python>=3.7.1